# Will I need to rebuild my application if I am to include a graphical user interface?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have an existing java application, I am a novice at GUIs, I'm okay at concurrency and networking in java. I am at the stage where logically, the server and client based programs are complete and working. 
I have had no experience with user interfaces in java or with swing or any of that. Will I need to rebuild my application if I am to include a graphical user interface for the client? Can I just create a new class or classes which are dedicated to the GUI element of the client side program? Anyone know a good set of tutorials for java swing or another appropriate library for this situation?

Comment: Since this is a general question about programming (lacking a specific coding question) you might have more luck over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com - what I've noticed is that building a GUI for an existing application usually also changes the backend to allow for such things as progress reports, display updates, etc.

Comment: What is the client side application now? A command line?

Comment: the client just uses scanner and a socket to send some text to the server which the server echos back

Comment: i just need a basic panel which can substitute for the eclipse console window. and i want to be able to change the colour of the consol

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to consider here.  The comment recommending a different location is a good start - you need to look at things like program structure, patterns etc.

That said I will recommend a few things to think about.

One:

What pattern are you using?  Was this designed into the back end?

A common choice for situations where you have a backend and you want a variable GUI is what is known as MVC or Model View Controller.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller

If your backend was not designed with this in mind, you would likely need to re architect to support that pattern.

As a general rule:  If your initial design didn't support a UI, you are likely going to have to do a lot of rewrites to support a new UI.   It's worth really considering the design of your systems early to avoid this exact issue.

Comment: No problem, if you feel it was sufficient for you please mark it as accepted.  Feel free to ask follow ups or for clarification if you need it.